# Replace a character in char* for double value

Tags: c, string

I have a `char *` and I need to replace a character for a double value (unknown number of digits). So I believe that I need to count the number of digits then make a `realloc()` and replace the characters. I'm just not sure how to count the number of digits and make this `replacement`.

For example:

```
char *c = strdup("a+b");
double d = 10;
//I'd like to replace 'a' for 10.  
//then 'c' would be : 10+b. 
//Next iteration I need to change the 'b' value then I get:
//c = 10 + 3
```

Comment: I'd like at least a comment explaining why the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: What is the practical value of doing this? Is it just an educational example? Do you want to read the double value from stdin? Do you want single/multiple iterations for find&replace? (PS: downvote not from me)

Comment: such as `int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%g", d);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char* s = "a+b";
  double d = 10.23142;

  //determine the string length needed for printing d
  size_t n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%g", d);
  // old string length + n - 1 for replaced b +  1 for '\0'        
  char* new_s = malloc( strlen(s) + n - 1 + 1); 

  //write the double
  sprintf(new_s, "%g", d);  

  //skip the first byte (where b is) at the source and the double's length at the destination
  strcpy(new_s + n, s + 1);     

  printf("%s\n", new_s); //prints 10.2314+b 

  free(new_s);
  return 0;
}
```

It's easy to make an off-by-one error in this kind of pointer arithmetic, so something like gcc's mudflap or AddressSanitizer are really useful in checking to make sure the program doesn't go into undefined behavior in some place.

Better yet, if you can, use C++ and you won't have to worry about this kind of stuff:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  string s = "a+b";
  double d = 10.23142;

  s.replace(0,1,to_string(d));
  cout<<s<<endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with realloc is that you may not necessarily get back the same address, so technically you may not so much replace the character as create a new string.

You could measure the size of double by printing it into a static buffer, and taking strlen:

```
char buf[32];
sprintf(buf, "%f", dbl);
size_t Len = strlen(buf);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/9PTsKO)

Now you can allocate more space, move the content to the back, and then copy characters from buf into reallocated space.

Comment: I tried it with `double value = 3` but `Len` is getting `15` as value. Also `buf` is getting a strange value like `"1456213"`